# How do you determine when a Windows Scheduled Task is completed?

Tags: windows-server-2012, scheduled-task

I'm using a machine running Windows Server 2012.  I have a scheduled task that indexes some files. This task takes around an hour or two to complete. However, I would like to know EXACTLY when it completes and also track how long it takes.

The best I can think of is to add a second 'action' to the task that writes to a log with a time and date using Windows shell.

Is there a simpler/better way to do this?

What I've tried:

I've tried adding columns to the task scheduler display, but there isn't one for time completed. I've tried googling how to do this and searched for existing questions here and didn't find anything. I'm not very good with Windows Shell scripts, so I'd rather avoid that if possible, but if there's no other way, a point in the right direction as to what command or commands would be required would be really helpful.

Comment: Have you looked at the task's 'history' tab in `taskschd.msc`?

Comment: It says history is disabled and I have not found where to enable it. How do you do that?

Comment: In the menu, 'Actions' -> 'Enable All Tasks History'. Without that enabled it will not have historical info.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to turn it on just for the one task? Or do I have to turn it on for all of them?